# How to solve Excel VBA: Compile error in hidden module

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h347l.jpg)
I have a problem about excel VBA.
Excel file is created for many years. It run VBA code in 32 bit excel.
However, my computer upgrade 32 bit excel to 64 bit excel.
I cannot run the VBA file anymore.

It show the error:
Compile error in hidden module.
This error commonly occurs when code is incompatible with version, platform or architecture of this application.

Is that any solution. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to the vba code?

Comment: Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/compile-error-in-hidden-modulemodule-name or try some of the suggestions here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2f9cb2fd-2141-46c5-a05b-8b5a12a649a5/this-error-commonly-occurs-when-code-is-incompatible-with-the-version?forum=excel.  Hopefully you have access to the original code :(

Comment: Is that Document critical? If so maybe consider to get the password to the VBA Module. There are ways described in Google how to achieve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved same error by following these 4 steps :

1. Open Excel file which is having issue, press Alt + F11 go into its Visual Basic Editor.
2. From the Tools menu select References ( Note, if references option is disabled in tools menu try closing and reopening file and enable Macro before proceeding next steps)
3. Scroll through the available References List and uncheck any item start with **MISSING**:
4. Press Alt + Q once all of these reference errors have been unticked.

If above steps does not solve issue try editing registry entries for 32/64 bit versions excel application.

This link has mentioned all troubleshooting steps
http://www.repairmsexcel.com/blog/fix-compile-error-in-hidden-module-excel

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if any missing variable declaration.
I had same issue and found out that missing declaration for one variable using for looping

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with the first-party Solver addin that is included with Excel.
The solution was to use Windows 8 compatibility mode.

[image]

[Original source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/when-opening-solver-in-excel-2010-i-get-a-compile/ce881c71-7c19-49e8-8b58-85cdb31864be)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had locked the project containing the macros I wrote. I was getting this error when I ran the bad macro without unlocking the project. When I unlocked and ran the macro, I would have detected the error and fixed it. Problem solved.

1. Open Visual Basic Editor
2. Run the same macro (that got this error)
3. Fix VBA errors
4. Save Project
5. Run the same macro

Answer (score 0):

Tried so many methods, nothing worked. But after uninstalling and resintalling office product fixed the issue. Its due to crashing of document cache.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).